# Installing @angular/cli at version 9 but then reporting version 7

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-cli

I am trying to update my global version of angular/cli to version 9, but after running the steps below I am still seeing version 7 installed.

Step 1

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
```

Step 2

```
npm cache clean --force
```

also tried

```
npm cache verify
```

Step 3

```
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

It uninstalls fine as when I run `ng --version` after the uninstall I do not see version of CLI installed. Yet, running this again after step 3 I see version 7 installed.

Answer (score 0):

You have updated it globally. Have you tried removing node_modules in project folder ?

```
rm -rf node_modules
npm uninstall --save-dev angular-cli
npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest
npm install
```